# Timescaledb jobs not running since a while now

Tags: postgresql, compression, scheduler, timescaledb

I have `timescaledb version 2.2.1` configured on a few servers ( all single-node deployments) and it has been working great for the most part.

On one of the servers, however, which is a relatively less powerful machine and with a large 100TB mounted NAS drive, the compression jobs I scheduled seemed to stop working once I set them for a large DB.

It did work for the smaller databases earlier, but when I created the hypertables on the largest DB ( total size of 13TB - with one table at 9.7TB itself ) and set up the appropriate compression policy, it just never triggered, even after I manually altered the job with the alter_job command. The same thing happened to the other DBS ( timescaledbs enabled ). The scheduled jobs stopped working on them too around the same time ( It has 29th Sept as the last successful finish date - ie. 20 days ago ).

I have tried manually calling the job and it only compresses one chunk at a time. So I had to manually compress them currently as a quick fix.

Can anyone please help? I cannot seem to find any resource regarding this.

```
SELECT compress_chunk(i,if_not_compressed=>true) from 
show_chunks('oa_odds_historic', older_than => INTERVAL '10 day') i ; 

   
 code: SELECT alter_job(job_id, next_start =>now())
-- select *
FROM timescaledb_information.jobs
WHERE proc_name = 'policy_compression';
```

**server spec :**
[image: server spec]

**timescaledb jobs:**
[image: timescaledb jobs]

Comment: Have you checked the memory available? Is there's any error popping in the PostgreSQL server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonatasdp.
Unfortunately, it was due to not having enough background workers -
**timescaledb.max_background_workers** ,which I increased to accomodate the total number of jobs ( = number of hypertables which had compression policies enabled ) on the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).